# rounding in matlab

Tags: matlab, rounding-error

i have a problem with the rounding that MATLAB does (automatically). In my loop the time increases by 0.05 second each time, or if there is a special circumstance, it will add a time value in between. So in order to get the next value, i used

```
    floor((t(n-1)/dt)*dt+dt
```

to calculate the next time value. Since floor((t(n-1)/dt) would calculate the amount of steps of 0.05 seconds so far, and it would it then multiply again with this timestep and add another step to get the next value. Even if the current time is not a multiple of 0.05, the next time step will be. Exactly what i wanted.
However matlab does some rounding i do not understand, see the screenshot below.
I even added a tolerance of 10^-14 to counter the roundings, but when the time becomes larger, the roundings will become larger than the tolerance.

As you can see in the screenshot, dividing 32.05 by 0.05 gives 640.9999999999999 instead of 641. And in my script this causes the loop to go on forever, since this is floored back to 640, meaning the time will never increase anymore and will stay at 32.05 at every loop.

*I need 10 reputation at least for an image, so here is a link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tNRC.jpg

**Edit:**
[image]

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Instead of adding `10^-14`, try adding `eps(t(n-1))` and see it resolves the issue.

Comment: What I find strange about your calculations is that the simple command 32.05/0.05 already gives an inexact result. Does this also happen when you restart matlab and then enter that as your first command (i.e. without first running any script whatsoever)?

Comment: no, this only makes it worse. The for loop is already in an infinity loop at 0.30 seconds now. esp(t(n-1)) results in 5.551115123125783e-17, which is much smaller than the old tolerance.
-----------------------------------
when i restart matlab, 32.05/0.05 gives an exact result of 461, but after i ran the script it will keep giving 460.99999999999 until i restart it.

Comment: Why not use `t(n) = t0 + n*dt`? (`t0` can be a multiple of 0.05 of course)

Comment: If it's not too long, add in your original code, or at least a minimal representative one that produces `n` and `t`?

Comment: So i added the simple calculation of 32.05/0.05 into my script on line 6. I close MATLAB and restart it. Then enter the same calculation manually. The answer is exactly 641, run the script, it calculates on line 6 and break on line 7. Result is 640.99999999
http://i.imgur.com/ChM0iyW.jpg

Comment: @user3446867 So, for that if you do - `(eps(32.05) + 32.05)/0.05`, it gives you perfect `641`.

Comment: Work with integers. Try to work with milliseconds unit. than you add 50 instead of 0.05.

Comment: @WouterKuijsters Nothing strange about that at all, no need to restart Matlab. Please learn about [floating point issues](http://floating-point-gui.de/). This surprises all beginning programmers, and even experienced people get bitten by this issue every now and then. This is similar to math in base 10 with limited precision, e.g. using only 3 digits, you have `3 * (1 / 3) = 3 * 0.333 = 0.999`, which is not equal to 1.

Comment: I added the solution of @Divakar to make it work.
        `t(n)  = floor((eps(t(n-1))+t(n-1))/dt)*dt+dt;`
So for me this question is answered, but because everyone posted a comment, i can not select that it is solved.

Comment: @user3446867 You can post what worked as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: @BasSwinckels Thanks for the article, I had heard about that problem but didn't expect it to appear for such a simple calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divakar gave me the hint towards the proper answer.
it was solved by using

```
 t(n) = floor((eps(t(n-1))+t(n-1))/dt)*dt+dt;
```

But most likely an alternative solution would be the suggestion of Mendi Barel, to convert the time to miliseconds so that all numbers are integers. 
Thank you all for the help and this question is solved now.